# How to implement swipeble bottom tab bar like Instagram camera filter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, instagram

I need to implement custom bottom tab bar as in Instagram camera filter in flutter shown in image below. Can someone give me an idea where to start it? I don't want the code. I just want the idea how to implement it.

[image].

Comment: this? https://medium.com/@uncoded_decimal/creating-bottom-navigation-tabs-using-flutter-2286681450d4

Answer (score 1):

I have build it the following app. Google Lens UI clone
https://github.com/RaashVision/google_lens_clone